# Order a table with MDX queries

Tags: sql-server, mdx

I have the following MDX query:

```
 SELECT    NON EMPTY {[DateT].[Year].[Year].Members  } ON ROWS,  
 NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Val] } ON COLUMNS    FROM [MyDB]
```

I need to order the data by year, so I tried this query:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY { Order ( [DateT].[Year].[Year].Members,Desc)  } 
  ON ROWS,
  NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Val] } ON COLUMNS 
  FROM [MyDB]
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong, and how I can fix it?

Comment: msdn should be referred to before S.O.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145587.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this solution

```
 SELECT 
  NON EMPTY { Order ( [DateT].[Year].[Year].Members,[DateT].[Year].Member_name,Desc)  } 
  ON ROWS,
  NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Val] } ON COLUMNS 
  FROM [MyDB]
```

if someone have another solution please share it 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the way to sort a set in MDX, you answered your own question.

Comment: @nsousa (imagine if this question about `sql` - `how do I apply `ORDER` in a `sql` script?` and tagged it `sql` .... what sort of reaction would that get from the S.O. community?)